# Adding (SELECTING) two more other columns to this resultset

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

**Suppose I have the following MySQL table:**

```
user_id    date_of_application   date_ended    grade    status    
---------------------------------------------------------------

 1            2011-01-01         2011-02-28     1.0     Ended
 1            2011-02-02         2011-03-28     1.0     Ended
 1            2011-03-03         2011-04-28     (1.5)   Ended

 2            2011-01-01         2011-02-20     2.0     Ended
 2            2011-02-02         2011-03-11     2.5     Ended
 2            2011-03-03         2011-04-28     (1.0)   Ended

 1            2011-05-10              -          -      Pending
 2            2011-05-15              -          -      Pending
```

- note that the table can contain multiple records of the same user as long as all its previous applications have ended (status = ended)
- **user_id** is not unique
- date is in **yy-mm-dd** format
- **date_ended** and **grade** are only updated the instant the application has ended

What I want to accomplish here is to retrieve all rows (together will all columns) **WHERE status is 'Pending'** and such that the value for the **grade** column for each of these retrieved rows is the value of the latest **grade** (in parenthesis above) where status is 'Ended' for this particular user (or row).

The result:

```
user_id    date_of_application   date_ended    grade    status    
---------------------------------------------------------------

 1            2011-05-10         2011-06-10     1.5      Pending
 2            2011-05-15         2011-06-15     1.0      Pending
```

----**EDIT**-----:

I'm not sure if I need to create another thread for these additions (' will do if I'm advised to do so), anyhow -- I decided to go with ypercube's answer (see below) (which works, minus the commented part). However, **in addition to the above resulting table**, I also would like to select two more columns (each from a different table):

Working code that gives-off the desired table result (see above):

```
SELECT user_id
     , date_of_application
     , date_ended
     , ( SELECT te.grade
         FROM TableX AS te
         WHERE te.status = 'Ended'
           AND te.user_id = t.user_id    

         ORDER BY te.date_ended DESC
         LIMIT 1
       ) AS grade
     , status
FROM TableX AS t
WHERE status = 'Pending'
```

Now I need to select these two other columns (**is_first_time_user** and **name**) together with the result table previously mentioned. Note that **user_id** for both of these tables are unique:

*Table2:*

```
user_id    is_firs_time_user
-----------------------------

 1               no
 2               no
```

*Table3:*

```
user_id    name  
----------------------

 1        User A
 2        User B
```

Comment: Do you have a query that you've tried but didn't work?

Comment: Does the table have a Primary Key?

Comment: What if there is no previous record, and the 'Pending' record is the only record for user_id?

Comment: @JaredFarrish I haven't looked through the answers yet, and the farthest I've gone so far is the retrieval of the latest grade based on a user I specify (which shouldn't be the case since I wanted all rows retrieved not just a specific user).

Comment: @ypercube Yes it does, but it's just a generic auto-incrementing id.

Comment: @wildplasser Oh in that case then that record itself is the one to be selected

Comment: @Angelo Tan: But in that case there will be no record to supply the value for 'grade'.

Comment: @wildplasser That's true. In those cases, what I do is to just display (this is in html) a string such as 'New applicant' just to notify the one viewing the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT user_d
     , date_of_application
     , date_ended
     , ( SELECT te.grade
         FROM TableX AS te
         WHERE te.status = 'Ended'
           AND te.user_id = t.user_id
           AND te.date_ended < t.date_of_application      --- not sure if 
                                                          --- this is needed
         ORDER BY te.date_ended DESC
         LIMIT 1
       ) AS grade
     , status
FROM TableX AS t
WHERE status = 'Pending'
```

Comment: suggestion: you can replace LIMIT 1 and ORDER BY on Subquery by: group by user_id and Select max (te.grade). What you think about this? I vote to you because your reputation is near of Larry's ;)

Comment: @danihp: No, it would not be same result. He wants the latest grade, not the highest. For `user_id=2`, that would yield `grade=2.5` and not (the wanted) `1.0`

Comment: The MAX(grade) may not be on the *last* (by date) record.  You have to use ORDER BY and LIMIT in this solution to ensure that you are retrieving the grade column for the most recent (by date) record.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. Larry, your query now is right, you forget ON clause on first try.

Comment: That is true, but what's an unexpected cartesion join among friends?

Comment: @ypercube I have tried running your query word per word and the only issue was the grade column returns a null for all rows. Removing the commented part of your query, as you might have though, fixed it. Thanks by the way!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that includes a derived inner table (ENDED) that contains only the most recent Ended record per user_id. (For clarity, I left out the columns that don't pertain to the question of getting the grade).

```
 SELECT PEND.user_id, ENDED.grade FROM YourTable PEND
    INNER JOIN 
       (
         SELECT user_id, grade FROM YourTable T1
         WHERE status = 'Ended' AND NOT EXISTS 
            (SELECT * FROM YourTable T2 
             WHERE T2.user_id = T1.user_id AND T2.date_ended > T1.date_ended) 
       ) ENDED
       ON PEND.user_id = ENDED.user_id
    WHERE PEND.status = 'Pending'
```

If MySQL has trouble with the nested SELECT, or if the concept of "most recent ended record per user" is one that you will use elsewhere in your application, or if you simply want more clarity, you can do this:

```
 CREATE VIEW MostRecentEndedGrade (user_id, grade) AS
    SELECT user_id, grade FROM YourTable T1
         WHERE status = 'Ended' AND NOT EXISTS 
            (SELECT * FROM YourTable T2 
             WHERE T2.user_id = T1.user_id AND T2.date_ended > T1.date_ended) 

 SELECT PEND.user_id, ENDED.grade 
    FROM YourTable PEND INNER JOIN MostRecentEndedGrade ENDED
    ON PEND.user_id = ENDED.user_id
    WHERE PEND.status = 'Pending'
```

Comment: The EXISTS subquery should include the `T2.status = 'Ended'` condition, because the row with the `Pending` status will (probably) always have a greater `date_ended` value than any `Ended` row (for the same user), thus always causing the NOT EXISTS condition to return `false`.

Comment: According to the data shown, the Pending rows have no date_ended value at all.  Indeed, I'm guessing that no date_ended value is the definition of a Pending row.  But if that's incorrect, and Pending can have a date_ended, then you're right.

Comment: Er, no, I wasn't thinking properly, sorry. Of course, there's more sense in assuming that `date_ended` is empty (NULL) for 'Pending' rows, I only now realise that. But then it becomes unclear where those `date_ended` values come from in the OP's example output...

Comment: @AndriyM Oh my fault. That's just a lack of proofreading on my part. I fixed it already --- 'date_ended and grade are updated the instant the application has ended'. ' Also supplied date_ended values for the result table.

Comment: @Andriy: There were values there before?  Honestly, I read them as NULL — I must have read the grade column and combined the NULLs there with my assumption about the date_ended values to manufacture NULLs where there weren't any.  Although, as it turns out, I had guessed right and the original data was wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way is to build a view with this query :

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(date_ended) AS max_date FROM table 
WHERE status='ENDED' 
GROUP BY user_id
```

then do this query to get the last grade for each user :

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.date_of_application,
   (SELECT t.date_ended, t.grade FROM table t, view v 
   WHERE t.user_id=v.user_id 
   AND t.date_ended = v.max_date),
   t1.status FROM table t1
WHERE status='PENDING'
```

Comment: This gets you the max date, but you'd have to join the table one more time to get the *grade* for that date record.

Comment: The view would contain one record for each user with the max date, then with the join we get only the grade corresponding to the max date (as we do t.date_ended = v.date_ended).

Comment: Or rather, it would get you the max date if the second query were correct.  As it is, it will not return anything (the pending record always has date_ended of NULL, and if it didn't, it wouldn't be the same as date_ended on the ended record).

Comment: @KayKay I'm trying to make the query you suggested to work. But I have a question, how do I actually use or incorporate the 'view' query into the second query? I'm using PHP so should I store the resultset of the view ($result=mysql_query($view_query)); then from there how can I make this work?

Comment: Angelo, once you CREATE the view in the database you refer to the view name in future SQL statements exactly as if it were a table.  When the view is used in a SELECT statement, MySQL will build an transient internal dataset from the view definition and use that.  For an example, see me answer elsewhere in this question.  The SQL in this answer will not return any records.

Comment: A view is like a virtual table. You can create it either with your administration tool which you used to create the tables, or directly with a SQL command : see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html. Then you reference it with the name you gave it, just like a table. As @angelo said the second query was wrong, I fixed it a bit (removed the status part) to give you the last grade for each user. It is not exactly what you want yet, since it does not merge with the 'pending' lines, but it should get you started.

Comment: I modified it again to merge with the 'pending' lines.